# 120yrs to 210yrs

Tags: number, midrash, egypt, adam, gematria-numerology

I learned over Shabbos that Adam and Chava spent 120 years apart. Adam spilt seed during this time that created the klipot. The 210 years Bnei Israel spent in Egypt was necessary to elevate those sparks lost by Adam Rishon.

The use of the same numerals caught my eye, with a difference of the one and two swapped. Are there any sources that explain the numeric significance to connect 120 year divorce of Adam and Chava with the 210 years of slavery?

Comment: They were separated 130 years, not 120.

Comment: Qelipos are the effect of creation, not anything Adam did. They are the remains of the "vessels" that the original "light of creation" was contained in. According to the Gra's school of Qabbalah, it is actually a second metaphor for the same step of creation as tzitzum refers to. Chassidus understands the ideas differently, but still, as an artifact of creation.

Comment: David, do you have a source? It's been heresay for me until now.

Comment: From [Rashi to Genesis 4:25](http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.4.25/he/On_Your_Way?lang=en): ‎וידע אדם AND ADAM KNEW — Lamech came to Adam Harishon, complaining about his wives. He (Adam) said to them: “Is it for you to be overparticular regarding God’s decrees? You do your duty, and He will do His!” He replied to him: “First correct yourself: **have you not lived apart from your wife these 130 years,** ever since, through you, death was decreed as a punishment?” At once, “Adam knew his wife further.” (Genesis Rabbah 23:4-5).

Comment: Voting to close, as it's a nonsense question, being that Adam waited 130 years, as already stated.

Comment: @DannySchoemann https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4109/13438

Comment: @Alex - I know that - I asked a "dup" (https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4613/501). But there are false premises and then there is nonsense. This has both; 120 instead of 130 and asking if 120 and 210 are related.

Answer (score 1):

No, because Adam and Chavah were not separated for 120 years, but rather 130 years. As per [Rashi to Bereishis 4:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.4.25.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi):

> וידע אדם וגו'. בא לו למך אצל אדם הראשון וקבל על נשיו, אמר להן וכי עליכם לדקדק על גזרתו של מקום, אתם עשו מצותכם והוא יעשה את שלו אמרו לו קשוט עצמך תחלה, **והלא פרשת מאשתך זה מאה ושלשים שנה** משנקנסה מיתה על ידך, מיד וידע אדם עוד וגו'. מהו עוד, ללמדך שנתוספה לו תאוה על תאותו:
>
> וידע אדם AND ADAM KNEW — Lamech came to Adam Harishon, complaining about his wives. He (Adam) said to them: “Is it for you to be overparticular regarding God’s decrees? You do your duty, and He will do His!” They replied to him: “First correct yourself: **have you not lived apart from your wife these 130 years,** ever since, through you, death was decreed as a punishment?” At once ‘וידע אדם עוד וגו “Adam knew his wife עוד ” — What signifies the word עוד? It is used here to teach that his love for her was now greater than before (Genesis Rabbah 23:4-5).